# why does text make my jbutton take up my whole jframe?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, text, jframe, jbutton

so i am using intellij and am trying to make a jbutton with text. it works fine without the text but when i put the text on it takes up the whole jframe and i do not know why. if you could help me i would greatly appreciate it. here is my code. Edit thank you Manchi for your answer it worked perfectly and i am no longer looking for answers but i do not know how to close the question.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Fantasyrpglifesim implements JButton {
    Fantasyrpglifesim() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MouseInputAdapter();
        //Frame//
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1500000, 1500000);
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Buttons//
        frame.add(BUTTON).setBounds(570,500,150,150);
        BUTTON.setText("Age up");

    }

    private static void MouseInputAdapter() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), in particular how [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) works, as a `JFrame` will, by default, use a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the layout of the JFrame. Add the next line to your code:

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```